# External Source Map Tool

Tags: javascript, uglifyjs, source-maps

I have a minimized file in production, with a an error handler that logs the errors, as well as the source map that was generated when I minified the file, however I have no way to map the errors to my source file since the errors are in a log and do not occur in a chrome or firefox where minified files and sourcemaps are easily consumed.  Is there an app or a tool that will convert the error reporting from the minified file using the source map I have generated to the location in the original unminified files?  So to be completely clear I have

`dist.min.js`

which is made up of several js files concated and then minified with uglify.js. I have

`dist.min.js.map`

which is the mapfile generated when the uglify minified the file.  What I need to do is take the error

`ERROR: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined, dist.min.js:1 
"TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined
 at distmin.js:1:21815 at ab.event.dispatch (dist.min.js:3:25564)
 at q.handle (dist.min.js:3:22314)"`

and figure out where that error is actually happening in my original source code. I know how to use sourcemaps with Chrome, but is there an external tool that will allow me to manually enter the line and column and bring up the location in my source code?

Comment: Have you tried http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: @DiegoZoracKy I don't want to prettify the source, I have the source and the map, I want to determine where in the source the error occurred.

Comment: Have you run jshint over it? Often problems with things like missing semi-colons only show up in minified code and can be a bit unpredictable. Sorry I know that doesn't help your original question but I thought I'd throw it in as it might make your problem go away if you haven't done this already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use mozilla's [source-map library](https://github.com/mozilla/source-map/) to reverse-map to the original positions, as follows:

```
var smc = new SourceMapConsumer(rawSourceMap); // <-- put map in there
console.log(smc.originalPositionFor({          // <-- plug positions here
     line: 2, 
     column: 28 
}));
```

Output is similar to:

```
{ 
  source: 'http://example.com/www/js/two.js',
  line: 2,
  column: 10,
  name: 'n' 
}
```

The example is straight from Mozilla's documentation. The same library is used to [generate the source-maps in uglifyjs](http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/) (links to the Mozilla project when mentioning source-map generation).

Comment: Just a small note: now SourceMapConsumer returns a promise, so you need to do `new SourceMapConsumer.then(smc => {...})`. Works perfect though.

Answer (score 4):

Since there wasn't a GUI tool already built for this, I quickly built [one](https://github.com/kriserickson/sourcemap-translator) based on [Electron](https://github.com/atom/electron) and the [Mozilla Source-Map library](https://github.com/mozilla/source-map/) that @tucuxi pointed out.

You can find it at its GitHub page: https://github.com/kriserickson/sourcemap-translator.

[image: Source Map Translator]

Answer (score 1):

Uglify.js has a thing named source map for such functionality. Please use following flag with command:

```
 --source-map yoursource.min.js.map
```

Whole command looks like:

```
 uglifyjs yoursource.js -o yoursource.min.js --sourcemap yoursource.min.js.map
```

More info:

http://tarantsov.com/WorkflowThu/source-maps-with-coffeescript-and-uglify-js/

Comment: I have clarified my question, it wasn't clear that I already had source maps but I do.  I need a way to get from source maps to the error line.